# Mobile app responsive until client establish connection with server

Tags: android, iphone, networking, mobile, user-interface

Is there a known / common pattern of how a mobile application should behave from the point it is launched (more the case of fast launch from suspended mode) until the point a connection with the server is establish and ready?

I'll try to explain, when the app comes from suspended mode, the UI is quickly shown, but for the connection it usually takes a bit more time to re-connect with the server.
Even more, a lot of time the app needs to re-login with the server so it will take some more time.

My question is, how responsive should the app be at that time?
Of course blocking the all UI is a bad idea, but should I for example block the buttons that trigger some network activity until the login phase is finished?

Answer (score 0):

I have the EXACT same issue with my App. A secure app that has to ping a server for login credentials after a programmer defined time-out or the user choosing to exit. I've found it to be better, from my very limited experience, to show a simple progress dialog that informs the user the App is connecting to the server for secure logon. My UI isn't blocked completely. The progress bar spins because the login process is always in an AsyncTask(Asynchronous Task). I hope this applies to you in some ways. I choose to make the dialog completely Modal so all other buttons beneath it aren't active. I also inflate my dialog to completely fill the screen to stop anyone who might have just picked up another person's phone from seeing sensitive data on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to cover the entire screen, I just don't want the user to initiate any network requests before he is logged in. User can still use the app to do non-networking stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You should do the server connection thing on other thread or use GCD.
In that way the main thread will be responsive and it will act accordingly on establishing connection with server.